# How all user login possible to wso2 identity server which having same domain email but not all users store in user-store

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have to one question that one user having email id with domoin name and stored in wso2 user database many another uses having same domain but not stored in same user database how those uses will be allowed to login in identity server only with same domain.

And second unrelated previous question is how to provide multiple user store with wso2 identity server

Answer (score 0):

First You have to enable email username as per [1]. You can plug multiple user stores as per [2]. Having same email domain in different physical user stores is not a problem. Authentication to WSO2 Identity Server is a unified functionality irrespective of underline user store implementation but if you want to authenticate against specific user store only, you can provide user store domain qualified username.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Using+Email+Address+as+the+Username

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Configuring+Secondary+User+Stores

Comment: My question is which users are not stored in database all allowed to login by using their email having same domain name already another stored user domain.

Comment: Your question is bit unclear however if you want to authenticate a user who is not stored in persistent storage. You have to write custom user store manager.

Comment: example "A@abc.com" is store in wso2 identity server but another user "B@abc.com" is not stored in wso2 identity server. yet "B@abc.com" is allowed to login in wso2 identity server because of domain name is same "abc.com".

Comment: How do you do authenticate operation (password validation) B@abc.com or else just by having "abc.com" do you allow them to authenticate ?

Comment: you mean without stored user in database we can-not authenticate user? and one more question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55000929/we-will-need-to-determine-how-we-can-create-the-wso2-account-from-that-account-i)

Comment: without stored user password, we can authenticate user but need to define authentication criteria something like need to authenticate against remote web service ...etc. so please clearly mention the way you want to authenticate B@abc.com

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but i have two requirement first is authenticate user based on domain name. and second requirement on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55000929/we-will-need-to-determine-how-we-can-create-the-wso2-account-from-that-account-i) go to this link.

Comment: For the first requirement if you are considering domain name only for authentication it can be done by writing custom user store manager and override doAuthenticate method.

Comment: I don't know that process. can you suggest me some references links to help me in authenticate user using writing custom user store manager and override doAuthenticate method.

Comment: please help me second requirement also that is most important requirement for me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55000929/we-will-need-to-determine-how-we-can-create-the-wso2-account-from-that-account-i)

Comment: I m trying to understand 2nd question but bit difficult

Comment: It is too difficult for me. am not getting exact way how should i do this.